# After Validation Hook not redirecting to the form page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, request-validation

I'm building a small validator for my form with laravel 7 and i needed a custom logic to be added after the standard validation so I  used the after validation hook as in [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#after-validation-hook). My issue is not with the logic of the controller but the fact that after the validation occur and I add the custom error message i don't get redirected to the original form. What I'm missing?

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $data = $request->all();
        $newSpn = new Sponsorization;
        $userId = Auth::id();
        $paymentPlanId = $data["payment_plan_id"];
        $apartmentId = $data["apartment_id"];
        $payPlanInfo = PaymentPlan::find($paymentPlanId)->hours_duration;
        $alreadyActive = $this->alreadyActive($apartmentId);

        $userApartment = DB::table('apartments')
                            ->where('user_id', $userId)
                            ->pluck('id');

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'payment_plan_id' => "required",
            'appartment_id' => [
                'required',
                Rule::in($userApartment)
            ]
        ]);

        $validator->after(function ($validator) use ($alreadyActive){
            if ($alreadyActive) {
                $validator->errors()->add('apartment_promo', 'A promo is already active on this apartment!');
        }
    });


    if ($validator->fails()) {
        //
    }

    $newSpn->apartment_id = $apartmentId;
    $newSpn->payment_plan_id = $paymentPlanId;
    $newSpn->start_date = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");
    $newSpn->end_date = date("Y-m-d H:m:s",strtotime("+{$payPlanInfo} hours"));

    $newSpn->save();
}
```

Comment: you have to do the redirect since you are only checking if the validation fails or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect back to the page where you come from like this

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->route('name.of.route.where.you.come.from')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```

As you want to be redirect to the **orignal form** you must define that behaviour when the validation failed so you can pass the validation errors and old input values calling the method `withErrors` and `withInput`